# Keeping grid order when using jQuery Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I am currently using [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html) to make a grid layout. Each item in the grid has the same dimensions, except when that item is hovered when it gets slightly larger. This causes a problem however and the grid becomes unordered.

[See example of issue here](http://jsfiddle.net/mitchmalone/q3fXt/1/) on jsFiddle.

Is there a way to force jQuery Masonry to keep the grid order (L to R, Top to Bottom) at all times? Either with options or by modifying the jQuery Masonry code slightly? If modification of jQuery Masonry is required please use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2356054) to make things easier.

Comment: Thought there was an answer, but it seems to not be the case.

Comment: You just have to compensate the grid to stop it from rejigging.. but it might mean larger gaps. Also top of my head.. maybe use position:realtive and flaot another div ontop of the original one that wont cause the grid to reflow..

Answer (score 1):

Try only manipulating the item that is being hovered (`$(this)` )
and you dont' really need to reload the masonry grid when doing this.

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nft3z/)